# AngularJS Динамическое добавление и изменение элементов списка

Tags: angularjs, select

Имеем форму в которой добавляем или удаляем некие аргументы, присваиваем им имя.

Как на основании количества аргументов и их имя добавлять в тег `<select>` - `<options>` с именами переменных, и чтобы имя `<options>` изменялось при изменении имя аргумента
[Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview)

```
$scope.indexes = [
    {argument:'$result', value:0},
    {argument:'$result_etalon', value:1},
    {argument:'$result_etalon_for_etalon', value:2},
    {argument:'', value:3}
];
```

Первых три элемента обязательные, 4-й обязательный но сначала пустой. - это элементы списка.
При заполнении поля имени переменной в форме, соответственно изменяется имя элемента списка. Так же если добавлять новые переменные. Как это реализовать?
Есть вариант с привязкой через `ng-model` в поле `input`, но тут модель связана с другим объектом - `args`, как параллельно связать модель с другим объектом, в данном случае с `$scope.indexes` неизвестно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте вынесем обязательные элементы списка в отдельную переменную:

```
$scope.src_indexes = [
    {argument:'$result', value:0},
    {argument:'$result_etalon', value:1},
    {argument:'$result_etalon_for_etalon', value:2}
];
```

Заполним исходное значение списка начальными данными:

```
$scope.indexes = angular.copy($scope.src_indexes);
```

И станем следить за любыми изменениями в списке `finalResult.arguments`, добавляя его элементы к изначальным данным списка.

```
$scope.$watch('finalResult.arguments', function(_arguments) {
  $scope.indexes = angular.copy($scope.src_indexes);
  angular.forEach(_arguments, function(add_item, _i) {
    $scope.indexes.push({
      argument: add_item.arg_name,
      value: _i + $scope.src_indexes.length
    });
  });
}, true);
```

Надеюсь я правильно понял задачу. [Пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/ByIHdSv1F35F6M3f6JZE?p=preview).

Comment: именно так. вот я еще свой вариант написал http://plnkr.co/edit/jsiVpVMtKzgmA0hI5KE1?p=preview

Comment: При смене модели повешал функцию $scope.updateList